# Return char value of a web page

Tags: c++

How can I capture the value of $mychar if the code on my website is

```
<?php

    $mychar= "S";

    echo $mychar;    

?>
```

I have tried with :

```
  char  Buffer;  
  DWORD BytesRead=0;

  const ::HINTERNET sesion = InternetOpen("agent",INTERNET_OPEN_TYPE_PRECONFIG, NULL, NULL,0);
  if(sesion!=NULL)
  {

   AnsiString Url = "http://XXXXX.es";
  const ::HINTERNET handle = ::InternetOpenUrl(sesion,Url.c_str(),NULL,0, INTERNET_FLAG_RELOAD, 0);
     if(handle!=NULL)
     {
       while (InternetReadFile(handle,&Buffer,sizeof(Byte),&BytesRead))
        {
           if(BytesRead==0){break;}
        } 
     }

    InternetCloseHandle(handle);
   }

 InternetCloseHandle(sesion);

 char result = Buffer;
```

result = '/n'

:-(

can you help me thank you

Comment: I assume you need to provide a `char array` rather than a `char`

Comment: I'm sorry I don't understand your comment

Comment: Try with for example `char Buffer[2]`

Comment: Thanks for answering I understand that I must replace char Buffer with char Buffer [2]

Comment: @neg1414 `char Buffer[2];` what only an example. By using `char Buffer;` you'll read one char at a time and only the last char will be saved. The `php echo` is not suppose to add a newline character (`\n`) but perhaps there's something else (like the webserver itself) that adds it anyway.

Comment: Thanks for answering, I have tested your proposal but the result is still "/ n" and even increased to buffer [100] and the same ..

I have simplified my web page to a minimum:
<? php
$ Character = 'S';
echo $ Character;
?>

but equal.